# Mix bold text to plain text in labels

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I save my **text** data in a **sqlite** database, I am able to store them, read them and etc.

To load it in The app I do something like this in page.xaml.cs:

```
new Label() {Text = myDbStringData};
```

However doing like that I can only save plain text, so here's my question, how can i store and read mixed text Bold and plain text in DB and then be able to show it in a Label?

I want to save something like this:

> Neque **porro** quisquam est qui **dolorem** ipsum quia **dolor** sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#Formatted_Text

Comment: @AndroDevil that is a bit different from what I am looking for. I want it to be in the same string or some similar trick that allows me to store only a string in my db.

Comment: @RiccardoRaffini Are you trying to store a single string into your SQLite DB? If yes what issue are you facing?

Comment: @FreakyAli actually there are multiple string but my problem is store and display as formatted string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you cannot store a formatted text in your data base. There is no way for it to what I know. However, you can format your text for the label using the `FormattedText` property of the Label and setting `FormattedString`.

Refer [Xamarin documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text) for more details.

Refer below example code.

```
<Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Hello Name, " TextColor="Red" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <Span Text="Welcome to , " Style="{DynamicResource BodyStyle}" />
            <Span Text="Xamarin Forms." FontAttributes="Italic" FontSize="Small" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

As of now the only way to store formatted text in your database would be to format it using HTML and save it. You can use the Display HTML feature of Label to render that in UI. [Documentation details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#display-html).

Refer below code more reference.

```
<Label Text="This is &lt;strong style=&quot;color:red&quot;&gt;HTML&lt;/strong&gt; text." TextType="Html"  />

<Label TextType="Html">
    <![CDATA[
    This is <strong style="color:red">HTML</strong> text.
    ]]>
</Label>
```

Comment: This seems right but my real problem is store the string and then split it easily in order to do that

Comment: @RiccardoRaffini : You don't have to split it if your requirement is to display the string from the database as it is. You can use the Display HTML feature as I have mentioned in my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to store and Read a single string into your SQLite DB then use TextType="Html" property in Label control.

like...

```
<Label Text="{Binding YourViewModelStringProperty}" TextType="Html">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Riccardo Raffini,

You can store Text in DB like this,
"`Neque <strong>porro</strong>`"

then in Xaml Add Text Type to Html,

```
<Label Text="YourTextHere" TextType="Html">
```

Hope this helps.